# Python Enhance Red

Tags: python

I am trying to enhance the red coloring in the picture below and I can't seem to get it to look the way it's suppose to. I'm not exactly sure how to manipulate my redPixel function to get it to work the way I need it to.

```
from cImage import *

def redPixel(pixel):
    intensity = pixel.getRed()
    aveRGB = intensity 
    newPixel = Pixel(aveRGB, 0, 0)
    return newPixel
def makeRedScale(imageFile):
    oldImage = FileImage(imageFile)
    width = oldImage.getWidth()
    height = oldImage.getHeight()

    myImageWindow = ImageWin("Enhanced Red", width * 2, height)
    oldImage.draw(myImageWindow)
    newIm = EmptyImage(width,height)

    for row in range(height):
        for col in range(width):
            oldPixel = oldImage.getPixel(col,row)
            newPixel = redPixel(oldPixel)
            newIm.setPixel(col,row,newPixel)

    newIm.setPosition(width +1, 0)
    newIm.draw(myImageWindow)
    myImageWindow.exitOnClick()
    
makeRedScale("butterfly.gif")
```

The version on the right* is the enhanced red I need.
[image]

Comment: The image on the left is your intended output. Is the one on the right what you're currently getting? And where's the one you started with? Explicitly including all three would make this a more complete [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).